# Resolving Git merge conflicts with inconsistent local code

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, visual-studio-2017, merge-conflict-resolution

I am having some confusion with resolving merge conflicts. It seems that my local code reflects changes I made and in other places changes that my colleague(s) have made- all before I've actually merged.

The very small image below simply demonstrates the environment of the conflict resolution tool:

- LHS: **Source:** src/.../AdminController.cs;Remote
- RHS: **Target:** src/.../AdminController.cs;Local

[image]
[Figure 1]

**Example 1**

Here is my local code before I've resolved conflicts and merged:

[image]

[Figure 2]

and here is a snippet from the conflict resolution tool:

[image]
[Figure 3]

This makes sense. I've removed the Braintree `using` statement and so the changes are reflected on the right as expected.

**Example 2**

Here is my local code before I've resolved conflicts and merged:

[image]
[Figure 4]

and here is a snippet from the conflict resolution tool:

[image]
[Figure 5]

This does not make sense to me. My **local** code in Figure 4 on line 775 reads `var currentUserLicenses` yet in the conflict resolution tool as seen in Figure 5, it shows that my **local** code (on the right) is `vm.HasCurrentLicense` while the **remote** code (on the left) is `var currentUserLicenses`.

What am I misunderstanding? Why is that in Figures 2 and 3, my local code was identical but in figures 4 and 5, my local code is not?

Comment: I don't know anything about the resolution tool you're using, but a proper tool should show you *three* input versions: base, local/`--ours`, and remote/other/`--theirs`. (These three inputs must reduce to one final output, which might or might not be in a fourth window or pane or some such.)

Answer (score 1):

The confusion starts with the thought that conflict resolution occurs "before the merge".  It actually occurs as one of the last steps of the merge, after all non-conflicting changes have been applied.

So the "target" window in your merge tool is *not* showing you "your local version" from before the merge.  It's showing you the tentative merge result - "I got this far, but these last few changes overlap, so you need to clarify the result".

Personally I don't like any of the GUI-based merge tools I've used, because they have a hard time clearly showing me "you changed this, they changed this, the tentative result is this".  With the textual mark-up that gits default merge driver puts in the file where a conflict occurred, I'm able to pretty quickly infer what I need to know about the four relevant versions (base, theirs, ours, tentative merge).  Now that's just what works for me; what tool gives you the information in a way you understand is for you to determine.  But I really would encourage you to find out how to see more than "source" and "target", because I feel information is being left out when you are given two views with those names.